# Missing 'accept-language' header in Express

Tags: node.js, express, http, http-headers, fetch-api

I would like to use value of `accept-language` header for detecting language in `node.js` server created with using `Express`. 
However when I try to get with headers:

`console.dir(req.headers)`

there is no `accept-language` field, other headers are present. But I can see 'Accept-Language' in chrome tab. 
I am making request with JS fetch with this configuration:

```
fetch('/path/somepath', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(input)
  })
```

What could be possible reasons of this behaviour and is something what I can do? I do not want to set this header explicitly in fetch because I would like it to create automatically on basis of browser settings.